# How can I treat a section of a file as though it's a file itself?

Tags: python, compound-file

I have data stored in either a collection of files or in a single compound file. The compound file is formed by concatenating all the separate files, and then preceding everything with a header that gives the offsets and sizes of the constituent parts. I'd like to have a file-like object that presents a *view* of the compound file, where the view represents just one of the member files. (That way, I can have functions for reading the data that accept either a real file object or a "view" object, and they needn't worry about how any particular dataset is stored.) What library will do this for me?

The [`mmap`](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html) class looked promising since it's constructed from a file, a length, and an offset, which is exactly what I have, but the offset needs to be aligned with the underlying file system's allocation granularity, and the files I'm reading don't meet that requirement. The *name* of the [`MultiFile`](http://docs.python.org/library/multifile.html) class fits the bill, but it's tailored for attachments in e-mail messages, and my files don't have that structure.

The file operations I'm most interested in are `read`, `seek`, and `tell`. The files I'm reading are binary, so the text-oriented functions like `readline` and `next` aren't so crucial. I might eventually also need `write`, but I'm willing to forego that feature for now since I'm not sure how appending should behave.

Comment: Can you just wrap a file object in a convenience class which has `read`, `seek` and `tell` methods which calculate the actual file position from the pseudo-position?

Comment: Also, how big are the files?  Are they small enough to fit comfortably in memory?  If that's the case, you may be able to chunk them up using `StringIO`

Comment: _"[..]but the offset needs to be aligned with the underlying file system's allocation granularity, and the files I'm reading don't meet that requirement."_ ... can you clarify this?

Comment: How can this be useful if you have to read the file to know what are the offset/length of the chunks? Or are they at specific positions, and you `seek` there and `read(1)`?

Comment: @Burhan, with `mmap`, I could map a view of the compound file and pass that mapped view around as a file itself, but `mmap` requires that each mapped chunk of file start at a multiple of the allocation granularity, say, 4 KB. My sub-files can start at any offset within the compound file, so `mmap` won't work.

Comment: @Jadkik, I only have to read the *header* of the file to know the offsets and sizes of the other components. I don't need to read the entire file. Using that, I could create a view like this: `fv = FileView(file, offset, length)`.

Comment: @Mgilson, if a simple is wrapper is all it takes, then I guess I can write it myself. The files could be multiple gigabytes, so I'd prefer not to load the whole thing, or even a sub-file, into memory.

Comment: @RobKennedy Sorry, you said `preceding everything with a header`, I missed the "everything" part, I thought each chunk was preceded by a header.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you were searching for a library, but as soon as I read this question I thought I'd write my own. So here it is:

```
import os

class View:
    def __init__(self, f, offset, length):
        self.f = f
        self.f_offset = offset
        self.offset = 0
        self.length = length

    def seek(self, offset, whence=0):
        if whence == os.SEEK_SET:
            self.offset = offset
        elif whence == os.SEEK_CUR:
            self.offset += offset
        elif whence == os.SEEK_END:
            self.offset = self.length+offset
        else:
            # Other values of whence should raise an IOError
            return self.f.seek(offset, whence)
        return self.f.seek(self.offset+self.f_offset, os.SEEK_SET)

    def tell(self):
        return self.offset

    def read(self, size=-1):
        self.seek(self.offset)
        if size<0:
            size = self.length-self.offset
        size = max(0, min(size, self.length-self.offset))
        self.offset += size
        return self.f.read(size)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = open('test.txt', 'r')

    views = []
    offsets = [i*11 for i in range(10)]

    for o in offsets:
        f.seek(o+1)
        length = int(f.read(1))
        views.append(View(f, o+2, length))

    f.seek(0)

    completes = {}
    for v in views:
        completes[v.f_offset] = v.read()
        v.seek(0)

    import collections
    strs = collections.defaultdict(str)
    for i in range(3):
        for v in views:
            strs[v.f_offset] += v.read(3)
    strs = dict(strs) # We want it to raise KeyErrors after that.

    for offset, s in completes.iteritems():
        print offset, strs[offset], completes[offset]
        assert strs[offset] == completes[offset], "Something went wrong!"
```

And I wrote another script to generate the "test.txt" file:

```
import string, random

f = open('test.txt', 'w')

for i in range(10):
    rand_list = list(string.ascii_letters)
    random.shuffle(rand_list)
    rand_str = "".join(rand_list[:9])
    f.write(".%d%s" % (len(rand_str), rand_str))
```

It worked for me. The files I tested on are not binary files like yours, and they're not as big as yours, but this might be useful, I hope. If not, then thank you, that was a good challenge :D

Also, I was wondering, if these are actually multiple files, why not use some kind of an archive file format, and use their libraries to read them?

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful. It might be nice to use a better-defined compound-file format, but our product has been producing files like this for almost a decade, so it's too late to change now. I have to write code to handle what the files *are*, not for how I *wish* they were.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how complicated you need this to be, something like this should work -- I've left off some of the details since I don't know how closely you need to emulate a file object (e.g, will you ever use `obj.read()`, or will you always use `obj.read(nbytes)`):

```
class FileView(object):
     def __init__(self,file,offset,length):
         self._file=file
         self._offset=offset
         self._length=length

     def seek(self,pos):
         #May need to get a little fancier here to support the second argument to seek.
         return self._file.seek(self._offset+pos)

     def tell(self):
         return self._file.tell()-self._offset

     def read(self,*args):
         #May need to get a little more complicated here to make sure that the number of
         #bytes read is smaller than the number of bytes available for this file
         return self._file.read(*args)
```